# How SQL Server indexing works

Tags: sql-server, indexing

SQL Server uses binary tree with intermediate and leaf node for search but how it will do this. Ex. If a table employee has two fields

```
Id bigint 
Name varchar(50)
```

with values such as

```
Id                  Name
1                   Ashish
2                   Amit 
3                   Bhavin
4                   Dinesh
```

If we have created composite non-clustered index on both of this columns with name as first and Id after this than how it work. Whether intermediate nodes contain 1) A-F 2)G-M ... or something else. Also once name is searched in binary then after this tree has id has intermediate node.

In short how does SQL server search in this type of conditions?

Comment: B+ tree is "Balanced" not "Binary"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**How It Works**

The database takes the columns specified in a CREATE INDEX command and sorts the values into a special data structure known as a B-tree. A B-tree structure supports fast searches with a minimum amount of disk reads, allowing the database engine to quickly find the starting and stopping points for the query we are using.

---

**For more info, check [THIS!](http://odetocode.com/Articles/70.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

This question is a conceptual one and requires a very straight forward answer
You can read this article for a short answer :

[How Does an SQL Index work](https://bitalksbi.com/sql-index-working/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it would benefit from quoting what's useful from the article in your answer in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. *[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*