# The best way to handle mysql database with 2.5M entries

Tags: php, mysql, large-data

I am developing a program (Webbased PHP, MySQL DB) which includes database of all cities around the world by 2.5M entries (all in one table). When I try to get the details from it, It took the server (assume localhost, wamp) so much time to search and grab the data.
I searched over the internet to find the most optimistic way to use such a large data.
One way, I think, is to shrink this table to different tables for every country to make the search process easier.

Could anyone suggest how to handle this and share the knowledge?

EDIT:
The table includes two columns. 1.`country` 2.`city`. I user `WHERE country=XX` to make the search process easier, But it takes a long time to process.

DATABASE: (table name: `cities`)

```
country city
US  Lakewood Estates
US  Lakewood Estates Mobile Home Park
US  Lakewood Falls
US  Lakewood Forest
US  Lakewood Gardens
US  Lakewood Harbor
US  Lakewood Heights
US  Lakewood Highlands
US  Lakewood Hills
.
.
.
```

PHP CODE:

```
$data = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM cities where country='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['country'])."' ORDER BY country" )
        or die( mysql_error() );

$i = 0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
    if ( strpos( strtolower( $row['city'] ), $q ) !== false ) {
        $i++;
        $arr[] = $row['city'];
        if ($i==10) {break;}
    }
}

echo "[";
for ($x=0; $x<count($arr); $x++)
  {
  echo '{"name":"'.$arr[$x].'"}';
   if ($x!=count($arr)-1) {echo ',';}
  }
echo "]";
```

Comment: It's not so much, MySQL even on VPS can handle much more. But don't forget about indexes and optimizing your queries.

Comment: Please add your table structure and query. That way we can see where you lack indexes and how you retrieve your data.

Comment: Indexes might help you.

Comment: it might be more wise to do a `LIMIT 10` instead of `if ($i==10) {break;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.5 million entries is actually not that much. You need to add proper indexes depending on the way you retrieve your data (`where` clause) then it will be way faster.

Add an index on country like this (first you need to change your column data type to `varchar`:

```
ALTER TABLE cities MODIFY COLUMN country varchar(255);

ALTER TABLE cities
ADD INDEX country_idx (`country`);
```

Comment: The table includes two columns. 1.country 2.city. I user `WHERE country=XX` to make the search process easier, But it takes a long time to process.

Comment: I got this: #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'country' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: Ah, I see. You can't add an index on `text` columns since they are too long. For your needs a `VARCHAR(255)` would be fine. So first change the column type from `text` to `VARCHAR(255)` and then add the index.

Comment: @ImanHejazi: I know it is a lot of change but I am sure it will be worth it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37572/discussion-between-iman-hejazi-and-juergen-d)

Comment: Thank you dear juergen d. It is wonderful. Could you explain me how it is working? It's amazing.

Comment: @ImanHejazi: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8892401/575376) short version of an explanation. It also refers to an article.

Answer (score 0):

It might more wise to do the following to only retrieve 10 values, but I could be wrong? Because you are retrieving all records `WHERE country = XX` and only using the first 10 returned records and discarding the rest of the records. Returning all records for a country might be slowing your query down.

```
SELECT * FROM cities where country='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['country'])."'
ORDER BY country LIMIT 10 (or what ever you want to limit to)

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
    if ( strpos( strtolower( $row['city'] ), $q ) !== false ) {
        $i++;
        $arr[] = $row['city'];
        if ($i==10) {break;}#remove this line
    }
}
```

Also maybe switching MySQL engines might improve execution.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What LIMIT 10 exactly do? What 10 items are selected? When I set `LIMIT = 10` the results will disappear.

Comment: @ImanHejazi `LIMIT 10` returns the first 10 results after sorting/grouping and such also the `=` shouldn't be in the LIMIT and it needs to be the last item in your query

Comment: Sorry for `=` It was misstyping. I'm considering this issue.

Comment: But I want to search between all records, NOT first 10. If I use this for instance: `SELECT * FROM cities where country='US'
ORDER BY country LIMIT 10` search always will be performed between 10 first cities of the table (inc. US)

Comment: @ImanHejazi No it will only return the first 10 records after searching and ordering them. if you want to have pages or such create a function that changes the LIMIT to something like `LIMIT 0,10` start at record 0 and give me 10 records for page 1 and page 2 `LIMIT 11,10` start at record 11 with 10 records, etc.